# VimScript - Save specific positions consistently even after buffer changes

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to save multiple positions in vimscript, and make sure that they stay at the right place, even after the buffer changes
Here are the solutions I found so far, and why I want something else:

- **Save them in an array**
  If lines are added by the user above the saved positions, they become incorrect (see below GIF, the gray position line `5` is the saved pos)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxVxx.gif
- **Position marks**
  This works better, but there's a limit of saveable position (52 for the 26 uppercases letters and 26 lowercases), and the user would be able to change them, I don't want that...https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cltpm.gif
- **Position signs**
  I haven't tried this one yet, but I don't really like it because it sets unnecessary signs on the left side of the editor, and it doesn't save the horizontal position...

Comment: How many do you need!?

Comment: Well, as many as possible? It shouldn't exceed 1000
But even if you have a solution for low amounts, that can help!

Comment: NB: It seems a Vim specific solution exists. See the [_double_ post of vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23244/626)